# Override javascript library function

Tags: javascript, jquery, overriding, spinner

Im trying to modify the behavior of the jquery UI spinner, and want to avoid hacking the original js file. Theres a function in the js file called _doSpin that if I modify I can achieve the effect I want (I want it to change the value by a percentage - not like the built in percentage method which presents a real percentage to the user, but I need normal ints to be incremented or decremented by a percentage without the bounds of 100% to 0%).

But I don't want to hack the original file, so I want to override the function from within my page (which uses ui.spinner.js). I cant work out how to get to the namespace of the library file, from within my html page. I've tried loads of tips from stackoverflow already but none seem to work in my case. The library file starts with  (function($, undefined) but I can't understand how its defined a namespace for me to define in my html page, so I can 'break in' and override the function.

BTW the function is used internally in the library file, maybe its not possible to override it in this case? I don't want to use it locally in my html page, I call higher methods to do my business, I just need to change how the library works internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, are you entirely sure that you can't solve your problem by specifying options to the spinner object?  It seems that with the `min`, `max` and `step` options you could make the `step` be any percentage of the range that you wanted at the time you created the spinner or set the range.  Here's [the doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#option-step) for the `step` option.

---

If this is an internal function (not exposed in a public API or as a method on a public object), then it all depends upon how it is coded.  If it is not put into a public namespace and it is defined within some other function, then you can't get at it to redefine it.  The internals of a function are not something you can get to from outside the function in Javascript unless they are explicitly make accessible to the public somehow.

If it is in a public API somewhere, then you can just assign a new function to whatever symbol the API is on and that will replace the original function (usually you save the original function first so you can still use it if needed).

---

We can't really help you more specifically without you showing us the actual code you're wanting to override.  FYI, I can't find a function called `_doSpin` in the [jQueryUI source repository](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui), so I don't really know which function in which code you're trying to override.

---

Edit: In a Google search, I found [another version of a jQuery UI spinner](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/source/browse/trunk/struts2-jquery-plugin/src/main/resources/template/js/plugins/jquery.ui.spinner.js?r=1604) that does have a `_doSpin()` method.  In that version the `_doSpin()` method ends up as a method on the prototype for the spinner widget object (which is a jQuery UI object structure it uses for all its objects).  I don't personally have much experience with jQueryUI, but from reading their doc on the widget factory, it sounds like you can inherit from an existing widget and replace methods on the prototype.  Or, you could probably hack on the prototype directly - though it would take some doing to figure out how/where jQueryUI stores it or how to get to it.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. Im not experienced in js hence the difficulty. The reason I could not use step was because the step needs to dynamically change, although maybe I could keep updating it on each tick of the mouse wheel, I didn't investigate that, but that would produce a lot of events (not sure if thats significant). It seems the version I was using did not match the docs I was referring to, which I discovered after you mentioned versions of this widget. They seem to vary wildly in their details and available methods. In the end it all seemed like such a hack that I started (cont)

Comment: looking at not using this widget but implementing the functionality directly, which in the end took me far less time that using the jquery widget. Your description made me aware that it was not trivial to get at the guts of the jquery widget and hence down the successful route of just attaching an event listener to each instance of the text box I had, and directly firing js functions. This was also much cleaner and accurate as I was able to keep my data in float arrays and avoid the rounding of the spinner widget. Ill post a code snippet for anyone who stumbles on this looking for similar.

Answer (score 0):

This did a better job in the end.

```
<html>
<script type='text/javascript'> 

var mainarray = [1,2,3,4,5];

function scrolltxtbox (e) {
    var evt=window.event || e;
    var delta=evt.detail ? evt.detail*(-120) : evt.wheelDelta;

    var targ;
    if (evt.target) targ = evt.target;
    else if (evt.srcElement) targ = evt.srcElement;

    (delta<=-120)?multiplier=0.95:multiplier=1.05;

    changeweight(targ.id, multiplier);

    if (evt.preventDefault) 
        evt.preventDefault()
    else return false
}

function changeweight(targid, multiplier) {
    var u = targid.match(/myspinner(.*)/); 
    mainarray[u[1]] = mainarray[u[1]]*multiplier;

    document.getElementById(targid).value = mainarray[u[1]].toPrecision(3);
}
var mousewheelevt=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel" 
var index;

for (index = 0; index < mainarray.length; ++index) {
    document.write('<input type="text" size=6 id="myspinner'+index+'" value='+mainarray[index]+' autocomplete="off"><br>');
    if (window['myspinner'+index].attachEvent) {
        window['myspinner'+index].attachEvent("on"+mousewheelevt, scrolltxtbox);
    } else if (window['myspinner'+index].addEventListener) {
        window['myspinner'+index].addEventListener(mousewheelevt, scrolltxtbox, false);
    }
}           

</script>
</html>
```

Its probably (definitely!) oververbose, but it works nice.